# 3d Entity Array Drawing On Screen

Tags: algorithm, 3d, screen, render

I'm making a 3D game. In the game, I have a list of entities that have a position in space.

What is the best way to draw only the entities that are on screen or within the radius of the camera?

For example, if I have 100,000 entities, maybe 10 of them are going to be on screen at a given time. It would be a waste to iterate through the entire array and have a:

```
if(entity.position.x > (camera.x-radius) || entity.position.x < (camera.x+radius)|| ..y..z)
   draw(); // or update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should partition your space with an Octree. You'll have to assign/maintain the objets in the Octree cells. With such structure, you may find quickly which Octree cells must be rendered, and then render the entities inside these cells.

This may not be obvious to implement, but you will probably get better performances ! This is even harder if objects may move: you must keep the octree up-to-date without iterating over all the entities.

Answer (score 1):

This is called *View Frustum Culling*. Here is an in depth [article with source code](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Frustum_Culling.shtml),

I also found an alternative, [similar article](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the kind of camera and view you are using. There are several possibilities:

#### 2D view or top-down terrain

You can use a view rectangle and test whether the bounding rectangle of your objects intersects with the view rectangle.

#### 3D view or perspective

You can use a viewing frustum (a cone-shaped volume) and test for each object whether the bounding box intersects with the frustum.